DOM is changed while js execution is paused at a breakpoint
There's the variable containerdom with a DIV inside which my widget is rendered. I attach a callback function to the widget's "render" event. In the callback I call containerdom.querySelector() to get the widget element that was just rendered.
Sometimes, usually after restarting Firefox, querySelector() returns null, but if I add a conditional breakpoint when it's null and re-inspect containerdom and call querySelector() again it returns the element this time.
    treetabledom = containerdom.querySelector('.widget-treetable-wrapper');
    if (!treetabledom) {
        console.info(containerdom.outerHTML); // child missing
        debugger;
        console.info(containerdom.outerHTML); // child present
        var treetabledom2 = containerdom.querySelector('.widget-treetable-wrapper');
        treetabledom = treetabledom2;
    }

What's causing it and how to fix this?
JS can't update DOM while paused at breakpoint, right? Otherwise this would soon print "after" (but it doesn't):



Sounds like something asynchronous is changing containerdom.

I don't see how outerHTML could be missing. It would be <div></div> if the div is empty.

Do you have an AJAX request that updates containerdom? Going into the debugger will allow the AJAX callback function to run.

To all commenters, when paused at a breakpoint, no async js can update DOM, right?

No, that's not true. The debugger doesn't halt async tasks. You can see this by putting a breakpoint after setTimeout(() => console.log("xxx"), 2000);

@Barmar What are you talking about? Your callback example doesn't execute as long as paused in debugger. See the new screenshot in the question

The debugger is indeed supposed to pause all JS execution, and thus new DOM updates shouldn't occur. What it may not pause though is the rendering, so it's possible new changes are painted to screen during the break. But the DOM shouldn't change. That could be a browser bug.
